# Replace old div content with new content

Tags: php, jquery

I am developing video Player in which XML is my playlist.
Here is code:

```
$crxml=file_get_contents('http://spoti.com/latest.xml/?lang=en');    
$rss=new SimpleXMLElement($crxml);
$playlistitem=1;
   foreach($rss->channel->item as $post)
    {   
    if($playlistitem<=8)
    {    
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li class="xtitle">'.$post->title.'</li>';
    echo '<li class="xdesc">'.$post->description.'</li>';    
    $dc=$post->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    echo '<li class="xthumb">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>';
    echo '<li class="xpreview">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>'; 
    echo '<li class="xsources_mp4">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';
    $dc->content->attributes()->url=preg_replace('/.mp4/','.webm',$dc->content-attributes()->url);
     echo '<li class="xsources_webm">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';
     echo '</ul>';
    $playlistitem++;
     }
```

I  want to replace the old content with new content when user click on Language all the entries replace with new entries

Comment: Are you using the jQuery Ajax function to get your XML?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#oldDivId").html(newContent);
```